# Avoid quotation marks when using \jobname or \currfilename

Tags: jobname, currfile

When typesetting a file (using TeXworks on a Windows machine) which includes white spaces, then the `jobname` will contain the file name enclosed with double quotes. `pdflatex Local\ Guide.tex` will set jobname to `"Local Guide"` and currfilename to `"Local Guide".tex`.

This is somewhat undesirable for me. Is there any way to eliminate the quotation marks? My corporate design requires the file name to appear in the page footer -- including the file extension .tex but excluding the quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quotes are (or should be) balanced 'behind the scenes'. Thus we can just strip off a set, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myjobname}{}
\newcommand*{\setmyjobname}{%
  \edef\myjobname{\jobname}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\setmyjobnameaux
    \expandafter\myjobname\expandafter"\myjobname"\relax
}
\newcommand*{\setmyjobnameaux}{}
\def\setmyjobnameaux#1"#2"#3\relax{\def\myjobname{#2}}
\setmyjobname
\begin{document}
[\jobname][\myjobname]
\end{document}
```

The idea here is that `"#2"` will match the 'real' name whether or not there were any quotes around the original name. We can't change `\jobname` (or rather we can't change the internal data which it uses), so I've called the 'simplified' value a different name. That also avoids the case where something else uses `\jobname` and does need the quotes.

Comment: Could you update this answer to L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>, please? While your answer from 2018 really is useful, it looks a bit outdated with all these `\expandafter`. Thank you! :-)